# Как отрезать слово до запятой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, строки

Есть строка типа:

```
NAME=ИМЯ,SURNAME=ФАМИЛИЯ,PATRONYMIC=ОТЧЕСТВО, IIN=123456789012, 
COUNTRY=СТРАНА,CITY=ГОРОД, EMAIL=ИМЯ@MAIL.RU
```

Нужно искать слово `COUNTRY` или (`NAME, SURNAME, CITY, EMAIL`).  Если есть такое слово, то сразу отрезать это слово до запятой, то есть `IIN=123456789012`

Как можно сделать это попроще на одной или не более двух строк?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var string = "NAME=ИМЯ,SURNAME=ФАМИЛИЯ,PATRONYMIC=ОТЧЕСТВО, IIN=123456789012, COUNTRY=СТРАНА,CITY=ГОРОД, EMAIL=ИМЯ@MAIL.RU";

// вариант через match

console.log(string.match(/NAME=(.*?),/m)[1]);
console.log(string.match(/SURNAME=(.*?),/m)[1]);
console.log(string.match(/PATRONYMIC=(.*?),/m)[1]);
console.log(string.match(/IIN=(.*?),/m)[1]);
console.log(string.match(/COUNTRY=(.*?),/m)[1]);
console.log(string.match(/CITY=(.*?),/m)[1]);
console.log(string.match(/EMAIL=(.*),?/m)[1]);

// вариант через split

var array = string.split(",");
array.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value.split("=")[1].trim());
  // в "value.split("=")[0].trim()" название ключа
});
```

Если нужно делать разбор с несколькими строками используйте `split("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'NAME=ИМЯ,SURNAME=ФАМИЛИЯ,PATRONYMIC=ОТЧЕСТВО, IIN=123456789012, COUNTRY=СТРАНА, CITY=ГОРОД, EMAIL=ИМЯ@MAIL.RU';
    let findStr = 'COUNTRY';
    let result = str.split(',');
    result.forEach(element => {
        if (element.trim().indexOf(findStr) == 0) {
            result = element;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: let какая команда? js ошибку выдает

Comment: "let" это тип переменной как и "var", тока чуть другая). ES2015
https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const

Можно заменить на "var".

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = 'NAME=ИМЯ,SURNAME=ФАМИЛИЯ,PATRONYMIC=ОТЧЕСТВО, IIN=123456789012, COUNTRY=СТРАНА, CITY=ГОРОД, EMAIL=ИМЯ@MAIL.RU';
    const result = {};
    t.split(',').map(v => {
        var T = v.trim().split('=');
        result[T[0]] = T[1]; 
    });
```

в результате будет такой обект

```
result = {
    CITY: "ГОРОД"
    COUNTRY: "СТРАНА"
    EMAIL: "ИМЯ@MAIL.RU"
    IIN: "123456789012"
    NAME: "ИМЯ"
    PATRONYMIC: "ОТЧЕСТВО"
    SURNAME: "ФАМИЛИЯ"
 }
```

чтобы првоерить есть то что нам нада так

```
if (result.EMAIL) { //
  // делаем что то
}
```

Comment: Ваш код отличный но как мне узнать что в обекте есть EMAIL или нет? как через цикл пустит этот обект и узнать IIN есть или нет?

Comment: обновил ответ   344

Comment: Здравствуйте! Санитариум ваш код отлично подходить для меня, Спасибо. не знал что так можно))) if (result.EMAIL) { //
  // делаем что то
}